# How does this list comprehension over the inits of itself work?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

In the #haskell IRC channel someone asked

> Is there a succinct way to define a list where the nth entry is the sum of the squares of all entries before?

I thought this sounded like a fun puzzle, and defining infinite lists recursively is one of those things I really need to practise. So I fired up GHCi and started playing around with recursive definitions. Eventually, I managed to get to

```
λ> let xs = 1 : [sum (map (^2) ys) | ys <- inits xs, not (null ys)]
```

which seems to produce the correct results:

```
λ> take 9 xs
[1,1,2,6,42,1806,3263442,10650056950806,113423713055421844361000442]
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how the code I wrote works. Is it possible to explain what happens when this code is executed in a way that an intermediate Haskell user would understand?

Comment: If you take the question literally, the correct definition is of course `xs = [0..]`, since the sum of the squares of all entries before the first is 0, and therefore so is every subsequent sum.

Comment: Un related to your question, but you could have written `let xs = 1 : [sum (map (^2) ys) | ys <- tail (inits s)]` instead.

Comment: @augustss I was looking for something like that but didn't think about it. That is much cleaner!

Comment: @SebastianRedl I guess that depends on whether or not you consider 0 to be a natural number...

Comment: @kqr I don't see natural numbers mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: you mean `[0,0..]` (or `repeat 0`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout You're right. Brain fart.

Comment: Another alternative: `xs = 1 : scanl1 (+) (map (^2) xs)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to lazy evaluation. Let's go with augustss's definition, since it is just slightly simpler, but call it `big` instead of `xs`, since that identifier is commonly used in utilities.

Haskell only evaluates code as immediately necessary. If something isn't necessary, there is a stub there, basically a pointer to a function closure that can calculate the value if needed.

Let's say I want to evaluate `big !! 4`. The definition of `!!` is something like this:

```
[] !! _ = error "Prelude.(!!): index too large"
(x:_) !! 0 = x
(_:xs) !! n = xs !! (n-1)
```

The definition of `big` is

```
big = 1 : [sum (map (^2) ys) | ys <- tail (inits big)]
```

So in evaluating the index access, the first thing that happens is that the correct function variant must be chosen. The list data type has two constructors, `[]` and `first : rest`. The call is `big !! 4`, and the first branch of `!!` just checks whether the list is `[]`. Since the list explicitly starts with `1 : stub1`, the answer is no, and the branch is skipped.

The second branch wants to know whether the `first : rest` form was chosen. The answer is yes, with `first` being `1` and `rest` being that big comprehension (`stub1`), its value irrelevant. But the second argument is not `0`, so this branch is skipped as well.

The third branch also matches against `first : last`, but accepts anything for the second argument, so it applies. It ignores `first`, binds `xs` to the unevaluated comprehension `stub1`, and `n` to `4`. It then recursively calls itself with the first argument being the comprehension and the second `3`. (Technically, that's `(4-1)` and isn't yet evaluated, but as a simplification we will assume it is.)

The recursive call again has to evaluate its branches. The first branch checks whether the first argument is empty. Since the argument so far is an unevaluated stub, it will need to be evaluated. But only far enough to decide whether the branch is empty. So let's start evaluating the comprehension:

```
stub1 = [sum (map (^2) ys) | ys <- tail (inits big)]
```

The first thing we need is `ys`. It's set to `tail (inits big)`. `tail` is simple:

```
tail [] = []
tail (_:xs) = xs
```

`inits` is rather complex to implement, but the important thing is that it generates its result list lazily, i.e. if you give it `(x:unevaluated)`, it will generate `[]` and `[x]` before evaluating the rest of the list. In other words, if you don't look beyond those, it won't ever evaluate the rest.

So, so far `big` is known to be `(1 : stub1)`, so `inits` returns `[] : stub2`. `tail` matches against this, chooses its second branch, and returns `stub2`. `stub2` is the list of inits of `big` after the omnipresent empty list, and it hasn't yet been generated.

The list comprehension then tries to give `ys` the value of the first element of `stub2`, so it has to be evaluated. The second result of `inits` is still known, it's `[1]`. `ys` gets that value. At this point, then, `big` is known to be `1 : stub3 : stub4`, where `stub3 = sum (map (^2) [1])` and `stub4` is the list comprehension after the first iteration.

Since `big` is now evaluated further, so is `stub1`. It is now known to be `stub3 : stub4`, and we can finally advance in `!!`. The first branch doesn't apply, since the list isn't empty. The second branch doesn't apply because `3 /= 0`. The third branch applies, binding `xs` to `stub4` and `n` to `3`. The recursive call is `stub4 !! 2`.

We need to evaluate a bit of `stub4`. This means we enter the next iteration of the comprehension. We need the third element of `inits big`. Since `big` is by now known to be `1 : stub3 : stub4`, the third element can be calculated without further evaluation as `[1, stub3]`. `ys` is bound to this value, and `stub4` evaluates to `stub5 : stub6`, where `stub5 = sum (map (^2) [1, stub3])` and `stub6` is the comprehension after the first two iterations. With `stub4` evaluated, we now know that `big = 1 : stub3 : stub5 : stub6`.

So `stub4` still doesn't match the first branch of `!!` (nothing ever will, since we're dealing with an infinite list). `2` still doesn't match the second branch. We have another recursive call, and then another, following the same pattern as we had so far. When the index finally reaches 0, we have:

```
big = 1 : stub3 : stub5 : stub7 : stub9 : stub10
stub3 = sum (map (^2) [1])
stub5 = sum (map (^2) [1, stub3])
stub7 = sum (map (^2) [1, stub3, stub5])
stub9 = sum (map (^2) [1, stub3, stub5, stub7])
stub10 = whatever remains of the list comprehension
```

Our current call is `(stub9 : stub10) !! 0`, which finally matches the second branch. `x` is bound to `stub9` and returned.

And only now, if you actually try to print or otherwise process `x`, are all of these stubs finally evaluated to an actual number.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I've read this a couple of times since yesterday and it's starting to make sense. No flash insight yet, but understanding creeps up on me slowly. I think I might have to re-do your work but with a pen and paper for myself, and really think of the evaluation order and sharing that happens. Thanks for a lengthy and thorough exposition.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'll try.

(I'm not sure what "intermediate" level you're looking for, so I'll explain this to myself in the hope that it's not too "sub-intermediate".)

`sum (map (^2) ys)` is easy: the sum of squares of a list.

The generator is also easy: `y` takes on all the non-empty initial sequences of `xs`, i.e. (abusing notation a little) `y <- [take 1 xs, take 2 xs, take 3 xs,...]`.

(I'll keep the `take` notation in the following, as I think it's pretty clear. It's most likely not what happens internally in your shiny Haskell machine.)

The only tricky thing is combining them, as `xs` is the value we're defining.
This is not a huge problem, because we know the first element of `xs` - it's `1`.
It's not much, but it's everything that's needed to get the ball rolling with `take 1 xs`.

Handwaving a bit more, `xs` is

```
1 : (sum (map (^2) (take 1 xs))) : (sum (map (^2) (take 2 xs))) : ...
```

that is (because we know that the first element is `1`):

```
xs = 1 : (sum (map (^2) [1])) : (sum (map (^2) (take 2 xs))) : ...

xs = 1 : 1 : (sum (map (^2) (take 2 xs))) : (sum (map (^2) (take 3 xs))) : ...
```

where we have the second element, and we can continue:

```
xs = 1 : 1 : (sum (map (^2) [1,1])) : (sum (map (^2) (take 3 xs))) : ...

xs = 1 : 1 : 2 : (sum (map (^2) (take 3 xs))) : (sum (map (^2) (take 4 xs))) : ...

xs = 1 : 1 : 2 : (sum (map (^2) [1,1,2])) : (sum (map (^2) (take 4 xs))) : ...
```

and so on.

The reason this works at all is that every element in the list only depends on the previous elements - you can always rely on the past to tell you what's happened; the future is less reliable.

Comment: Thanks. Viewing `tail (inits xs)` as the infinite list of increasing `take`s was inventive and actually helpful to fundamentally understand what the code does. I still have a hard time linking it to the actual execution of the Haskell machine, but I guess that's where Sebastians answer is a nice complement. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @kqr One thing I've learned about the actual execution of Haskell is that thinking about it very hard doesn't help that much ;-)  [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/PAGES/III.HTM) [Peyton-Jones et al] is available online if you want to dig really deep. It's very readable.

Comment: So true! In some cases my curiosity wins, though... And ach, That book is expensive for someone who prefers the dead-tree format. :(

Answer (score 1):

Shaking your code a bit until it settles into a more comprehensible form, we get

```
xs = 1 : [sum (map (^2) ys) | ys <- inits xs, not (null ys)]
   = 1 : (map (sum . map (^2)) . map (`take` xs)) [1..]
   = 1 : map (sum . map (^2) . (`take` xs)) [1..]
   = 1 : scanl1 (\a b-> a+b^2) xs
   = x1 : xs1
              where { x1  = 1; 
                      xs1 = scanl1 g xs 
                          = scanl g x1 xs1;   -- by scanl1 definition
                      g a x = a+x^2 }
```

`scanl` works for non-empty lists as

```
scanl g a xs = a : case xs of (h:t) -> scanl g (g a h) t
```

so `xs1 = scanl g a xs1` will first put the currently known accumulating value at its output's head (`xs1 = (a:_)`), and only then will it read that output, so this definition is productive. We also see that `h = a`, so `g a h = g a a = a+a^2 = a*(a+1)` and we can code this stream purely iteratively, as

```
xs = 1 : iterate (\a -> a*(a+1)) 1
```