# Demonstrating Lazy evaluation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

This is a question from one of my homework assignments that I haven't been able to answer. It's to do with reasoning about Haskell code by demonstrating how the Haskell compiler (interpreter?) executes programs.

I'm given a few different functions...

```
-- built-in
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a] 
take 0 _ = [] 
take n (x:xs) = x : (take (n - 1) xs) 

-- exchanging entries
exchange :: [a] -> [a] 
exchange [x,y] = [y,x] 
exchange (x:y:xs) = (y:x:(exchange xs))

-- picking even numbered entries
evens :: [a] -> [a] 
evens [x,y] = [x] 
evens (x:_:xs) = x:(evens xs) 

-- first four numbers repeated
first_four :: [Int] 
first_four = 1:2:3:4:first_four
```

Now I have to demonstrate understanding of Lazy Evaluation by "pretending to be the compiler". By breaking down how this statement would be executed...

```
> take 5 (evens (exchange first_four))
[2,4,2,4,2]
```

I'm given the first few lines to help get started...

```
take 5 (evens (exchange first_four)) =
take 5 (evens (exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four))) =
take 5 (evens (2:1:(exchange (3:4:first_four)))) =
...
```

I'd like some help with understanding how lazy evaluation works so I can do this question.

Comment: Have you tried reading any of the numerous resources already available online before coming here?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes

Comment: I once wrote a detailed evaluation chain for a Haskell function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898999/how-does-this-list-comprehension-over-the-inits-of-itself-work/29900144#29900144 Maybe that will help you.

Comment: I think the first evaluation step here is not very honest if you really should explain the lazy-part ...

Comment: @SebastianRedl That does help thank you

Comment: @Carsten Indeed, those lines are just plain wrong.

Comment: @Carsten that's what I was thinking too, but actually, `evens` demands at least 3 elements from its input, and `exchange` only knows how to produce them by pairs, so demands them by pairs too from its supplier. to produce three, it must have four of them. :) this is a really trickily written code. (normally, it'd be `evens [] = [] ; ...` same for `exchange`).

Comment: @WillNess if you want to demonstrate laziness you have to begin by "expanding" `take` first (the rest can stay a unevaluated thunk for now) - and that is just the beginning

Comment: @WillNess look I don't think that us arguing will help anyone and it's a minor point but I would start the evaluation by rewriting first take and then `evens`, ... you now like `take 0 undefined`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat your definitions as re-write equations, and always (*uniquely*) name the interim entities as they come into play:

```
take 5 (evens (exchange first_four))
  -- match: take 0 .... = ....    ? FAIL
  -- match: take n (x:xs) = ....   ? SUCCESS
  n1 = 5 
  (x1:xs1) ?= evens (exchange first_four)   
    -- evens [x,y] = ....
    [x2,y2] ?= exchange first_four
      -- exchange [x,y] = ....
      [x3,y3] ?= first_four
  ......
```

etc. The operation is mechanical. "Laziness" here means, we proceed left-to-right, never trying to find out values of expressions too soon, only doing so when we actually need to pattern match some definition with them.

Here's what I meant by *"naming"* the *interim* entities:

```
take 5 (evens (exchange first_four)) =
take 5 xs   where xs = evens (exchange first_four)
       (x1:xs1) ?= xs  -- <---- THIS
                 = evens (exchange first_four)
                 = evens ys   where ys = exchange first_four
                         [x2,y2] ?= ys  -- <--- AND THIS
                         .     .  = exchange first_four
                         .     .          -- ^^ <--- already named
                         .     .       [x3,y3] ?= first_four
                         .     .               FAIL
                         .     .       (x3:y3:xs3) ?= first_four
                         .     .                    = 1:2:3:4:first_four
                         .     .               SUCCESS: x3=1
                         .     .                        y3=2
                         .     .                        xs3=3:4:first_four
                         .     .   ys = y3:x3:exchange xs3   !
                         .     .   [] ?= exchange xs3
                         .             = ...
                         .             FAIL
                         (x2:_:xs2) ?= ys
                                       SUCCESS: x2=y3
                                                xs2=...
```

Of course working to this fine details resolution is very tiresome and seldom needed, only perhaps to track some "timing" issues; it is easier to see what each definition does, separately, and treat them as separate producers connected in a chain.

By "timing" I mean, whether the "inner" producer is ready to produce its element when the "outer" one needs it. because if not, the whole process becomes stuck, *"non-productive"*. Here the most inner producer is an infinite stream, directly defined, so there's no such problems.

So mentally, we could say to ourselves: "`first_four` is infinite repeating stream of 1 to 4; `exchange` swaps each pair of elements it gets; `evens` throws away every element in odd position; `take` takes n elements".

**So actually, it turns out *you were right all along*.**

Because of how the definitions are written, `evens` forces out of `exchange` its output elements in groups of four, more or less. Mainly, the culprit is the unnecessary matching for `[x,y]` in `evens` and `exchange`, which demands *three* elements from its input, to see whether the tail is empty (`[]`) or not.

`evens` demands three elements, but `exchange` only knows how to produce them by pairs.

But `exchange` too demands at least three elements from its supplier. So, coarsely:

```
take 5 (evens (exchange first_four))
take 5 (evens (exchange first_four))
take 5 (evens (exchange (1:2:3:(4:first_four)))
take 5 (evens (2:1:exchange (3:4:1:(2:3:4:first_four))))
take 5 (evens (2:1:4:(3:exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four))))
take 5 (2:evens (4:3:exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four)))
2:take 4 (evens (4:3:exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four)))
2:take 4 (evens (4:3:2:(1:exchange (3:4:first_four))))
2:take 4 (4:evens (2:1:exchange (3:4:first_four)))
2:4:take 3 (evens (2:1:exchange (3:4:1:(2:3:4:first_four))))
2:4:take 3 (evens (2:1:4:(3:exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four))))
2:4:take 3 (2:evens (4:3:exchange (1:2:3:4:first_four)))
........
```

I'm sure you can finish this now. :)

To illustrate, here's `exchange` looked at *procedurally*, as a stream transformer, which can `pull` an element from its input; `peek` whether its input has an element ready to be pulled; and `push` an element into its output.

```
exchange:
   pull(X)  ...  on_fail: ERROR
   pull(Y)  ...  on_fail: ERROR
   peek     ...  on_fail: push(Y); push(X); STOP
   push(Y); push(X)
   LOOP
```

Comment: Kinda I don't know what interim entity means though

Comment: the `x1` and the `xs1`, etc. What *forces* the calculation of an expression's value is the need to pattern match it, when that need arises. like with `take`, the `take 0 ... = ...` doesn't match the  call `take 5 (...)`; so we move on to the next clause in `take`'s defintion, and try to match the call `take 5 (...)` with `take n (x:xs) = ...`. So `n` matches with 5, by registering `n = 5`. Next, we must see whether `(evens ...)` matches with `(x:xs)` (but, we renamed them to `x1:xs1` (NB!)). So we go on to see the definition of `evens`. And so on. -- don't hesitate to ask more. :)

Comment: Ok I think I get it am I on the right track with this? ... take 5 (evens (2:1:(exchange (3:4:first_four)))) = `take 5 (2:(evens (exchange 3:4:first_four)))`

Comment: turns out your were right all along. :) `even` demands 3 elements, but `exchange` only know how to produce them in pairs.